# Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::port

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, port

I'm a newbie, learning JS. When I tried to write on terminal command "node index.js" to run my nodejs program. It connected through the port 3000. Then I exit program by "Ctrl + Z" (I tried with C but didn't work). Program did exit but next time I tried "node index.js", it said Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000. Then I checked this error and found a solution by kill PID with the command "kill -9 port" but it only work once, then I have to do it again, I also try to connect and run a static web on aws, same error happened but with another port. I don't want to kill and run again and again like this, so hope someone can help me out of this annoying problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl+C` should work. It is supposed to send a `SIGINT` signal to the process allowing it to end gracefully. There is no workaround on this; you always have to kill the node process.

Most of the developers I work with use `npm` or `pm2` to manage their startup and stopping of their node application. For example, in the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js",
  "stop": "node stop.js"
}
```

### stop.js:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socketClient = io.connect('http://localhost'); // Specify port if your express server is not using default port 80

socketClient.on('connect', () => {
  socketClient.emit('npmStop');
  setTimeout(() => {
    process.exit(0);
  }, 1000);
});
```

This way, not only do you have a graceful way of stopping your application, but also you can add whatever additional steps you want to happen before the application exits.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe there is something wrong with my computer, I press Ctrl + C for thousands times but didn't work. will try to understand the package json file like you said